# Edit theme wp_head

Tags: themes, child-theme

My wordpress render in the head tag lots of unneeded script or css files, I tried to fix this by editing my `head.php` page but the theme I was using (`zerif`) use `wp_head` function to include all the scripts files.

I tried to see where I could edit the output of the function I took a look to the wordpresss documentation

They said that every theme specifies this with `do_action("wp_head")` .

I searched for that on my theme code but I didn't find anything, so how can I edit this ? 
 Should I hard code everything without using `wp_head()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove some default WP links of the `head` by using `remove_action()`. For example:

```
// Removes the wlwmanifest link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );
// Removes the RSD link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
// Removes the WP shortlink
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0 );
// Removes the canonical links
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
// Removes the links to the extra feeds such as category feeds
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 ); 
// Removes links to the general feeds: Post and Comment Feed
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); 
// Removes the index link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' ); 
// Removes the prev link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link' ); 
// Removes the start link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link' ); 
// Removes the relational links for the posts adjacent to the current post
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head' );
// Removes the WordPress version i.e. -
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
```

To remove the emoji support (CSS and Javascript):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

You must use them in your `functions.php` file.

To edit the files enqueued by your theme (zerif) you will need to edit the `functions.php` file, as well. For example, you will find something like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'shortcodes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shortcodes.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

If you don't find it in your `functions.php`, it's because some themes divide the `functions.php` content among several files, normally included into a specific folder with the name `inc`, `include` or `framework`. That's easy to know: these files must be loaded into your `functions.php`. For example:

```
locate_template( 'inc/widgets.php', true, true );
locate_template( 'inc/sidebars.php', true, true );
locate_template( 'inc/breadcrumbs.php', true, true );
locate_template( 'inc/whatever.php', true, true );
```